# WooCommerce CSV Import Suite Creating Duplicate Products

Tags: csv, woocommerce

We are trying to get the CSV importer to work properly and we're having issues because it's creating duplicate products. Ultimately we want to import hundreds of product variations, but we're not close to getting that working yet. We've eliminated all of the possible variables that we can think of to getting this to work and we have a pretty simple test that's failing.

What we did was this:

1. Export all of the products (WooCommerce >> CSV Import Suite >>
   Export Products Tab, Limit = unlimited, Offset=0, Columns = All
   Columns. We've tested it with "include hidden data" checked and
   unchecked.)
2. Save the CSV file to the desktop (Windows) and didn't
   open it or edit it in any way.
3. Click on the import button, upload the files and click on the final button to start the process.

I would expect it to skip every product in the import file because it already exists in the database, but it routinely adds 8 of the 67 products as new ones. Each time we've tested has been the same 8 products and the option for including hidden data on the export doesn't impact the results.

Has anyone seen this issue?  Any ideas on a workaround or fix?

If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how to de-duplicate the records?

Answer (score 1):

Check the ID column.  If it's a new product you're gonna want to make the ID cell blank.

Answer (score 1):

woocommerce CSV product import suite does not need the post id but to know whether you are updating creating or removing the correct attributes; from a variation you will always need a unique sku , if you just use the parents sku or the same for every variation you end up with duplicates or missing variation; due to attributes changing but sku being the same.

Woocommerce seems to care more for the sku over attributes it is also not smart enough to account for missing attributes. GIST is UNIQUE SKU ALWAYS, if uploading to existing products and not sure if attributes have changed; use override to remove blank cells this will clear unwanted attributes not in use.